# Unique emails in string

Tags: string, bash, unique

I have a string with emails, some duplicated. For example only:

```
"aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com"
```

I would like string to contain only unique emails, comma separated. Result should be:

```
"aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com"
```

Any easy way to do this?

P.S. emails vary, and I don't know what they will contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
echo "aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com" |
  tr ',' '\n' |
  sort |
  uniq |
  tr '\n' ',' |
  sed -e 's/,$//'
```

I convert the separating commas into newlines so that I can then use tools (like `sort`, `uniq`, and `grep`) that work with lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and [`process-substitution`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) only than to use `sort` and other tools.

```
awk  -vORS="," '!seen[$1]++' < <(echo "aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com" |   tr ',' '\n') 
aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com
```

Or another way to use pure-bash and avoid `tr` completely would be

```
# Read into a bash array with field-separator as ',' read with '-a' for reading to an array
IFS=',' read -ra myArray <<< "aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com"


# Printing the array elements new line and feeding it to awk
awk  -vORS="," '!seen[$1]++' < <(printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}")
aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```
$ s="aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com"
$ echo $s | perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -F, -le 'print join ",",uniq(@F)'
aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the strings in an array:

```
IFS=','; read -r -a lst <<< "aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,aaa@company.com,bbb@company.com,ccc@company.com"
```

Sorting and filtering:

```
IFS=$'\n' sort <<< "${lst[*]}" | uniq
```